# values() returns datetime with tzinfo = UTC in default, can I change the default timezone before calling values()?

Tags: django, django-queryset

```
{'began_datetime': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 7, 2, 18, 3, 644392, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
```

For example, values() return something like this. But I want it return the datetime with timezone = settings.TIME_ZONE. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `timezone.now()` it's using the zone define in the settings.py by default but you can change it, see the documentation about [selecting the current time zone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone).

You have 3 choices:

- MIDDLEWARE
- View
- Template

Don't forget to install pytz for using midlleware or view : `pip install pytz`. Else if you to do it in the template:

```
{% load tz %}

{% timezone "Europe/Paris" %}
    Paris time: {{ value }}
{% endtimezone %}

{% timezone None %}
    Server time: {{ value }}
{% endtimezone %}
```